# How to populate List<Integer> from IntStream?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I want to populate List with `numberOfElements` elements of random Integers in a range of 0 to `numberOfElements/10`.
Why method `populateListStream1()` works and `populateListStream2()` does not work?

```
public static List<Integer> populateListStream1(int numberOfElements) {
    return Stream.generate(new Random()::nextDouble)
            .limit(numberOfElements)
            .map(e -> (int)(e*numberOfElements/10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<Integer> populateListStream2(int numberOfElements) {
    return IntStream.range(0,numberOfElements)
            .map(e -> random.nextInt(numberOfElements/10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you elaborate? Is it throwing an error? which one? is it providing incorrect output?

Comment: Why are you trying to fill a `List<Integer>` with random **`double`(s)**?

Comment: Note that `Random` offers `ints()` and `doubles()` to simplify random stream generation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second example [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) from the `Random` class returns a primitive `int`, which can't be collected to a `List`. Add a call to `boxed`, which will convert the `int`'s to their wrapper class `Integer`:

```
public static List<Integer> populateListStream2(int numberOfElements){
    return IntStream.range(0,numberOfElements)
                    .map(e -> random.nextInt(numberOfElements/10))
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

> But the first one also returned a primitive int through casting!

Yes, but it was in a `Stream`, so it was autoboxed to an `Integer`. You can tell by running:

```
Stream.generate(new Random()::nextDouble)
        .limit(numberOfElements)
        .map(e -> (int)(e*numberOfElements/10))
        .peek(e -> System.out.println(e.getClass()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which prints:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

The latter was an `IntStream`. One of `IntStream`'s benefits is to avoid auto boxing and unboxing. It won't box unless you explicitly call `boxed()`

---

<sub>Also note that there are methods from the `Random` class that already return a `Stream` of random numbers such as [`ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints--) and [`doubles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles--)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. 
.boxed() solved my problem.
I had the same thought so I tried with .map(e->Integer::valueOf) but that did not help.

Comment: Also thanks for:  return random.ints(0,numberOfElements/10)
                                               .limit(numberOfElements)
                                               .boxed()
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

Box `int` it to it's wrapper corresponding class `Integer`. Also, you can try something like:

```
  public static List<Integer> populateListStream3(int numberOfElements) {
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new Random().ints(numberOfElements, 0, numberOfElements/10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return listOfIntegers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one does not work, because you are using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) which contains primitive int types. You have to call [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) before `map()`. But a better solution would be to use [`mapToObj()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) instead of `map()`:

```
public static List<Integer> populateListStream2(int numberOfElements) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numberOfElements)
            .mapToObj(e -> random.nextInt(numberOfElements / 10))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In this case the values are autoboxed as they are in your `populateListStream2()` method.

Alternatively I would recommend using [`Random.ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) to generate a Stream of ints.